# blazor bootstrap scss _reboot is overriding variable selectors. Blazor Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, user-interface, sass, blazor

When i custom style a button notice that the text is not perfectly centered? for some reason even when i pass the important! tag to the css this is still overriden by this _reboot scss file. I have read some places that this is an issue with bootstrap which i currently have in my build. does anyone have a solution for this?

[image]

Edit

after deleting bootstrap from the project this does remove the issue however a plethora of other styling issues occur now. So i need a more targeted solution. also using id tags does not work. see image below.

[image]

Comment: `none` is not a valid value for `line-height`. This is why it has the yellow triangle icon next to it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here while _reboot has been an apparent issue on several other Questions was simply assigning the following css selectors to the class.

```
button{
  line-height: normal;
  font-size: unset;
}
```

Mister Magoo was correct in his comment on the initial post.